# How to prevent running same make command twice?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got these two `make` targets:

```
NPM_OUT = node_modules/npm.sfv
NPM_BIN = $(shell command -v npm || command -v /usr/bin/npm || echo "npm")
HASH_CMD = $(shell command -v md5 || command -v md5sum)

$(NPM_OUT): npm-shrinkwrap.json
    $(NPM_BIN) install --loglevel=error
    @$(HASH_CMD) npm-shrinkwrap.json > $(NPM_OUT)

npm-shrinkwrap.json:
    $(NPM_BIN) install --loglevel=error
    $(NPM_BIN) prune
    $(NPM_BIN) dedupe
    $(NPM_BIN) shrinkwrap --dev
```

`NPM_OUT` is basically a bogus file I use just to determine if `npm install` has been ran yet. I don't know how to do this without a bogus file because that one command generates *many* output files, not just one object file like you'd see in c/c++.

The problem I'm having is that if `npm-shrinkwrap.json` doesn't exist then `npm install --loglevel=error` gets ran twice.

As you can see, it exists in both targets. If `npm-shrinkwrap.json` doesn't exist, then I need to run `npm install` before I can create the shrinkwrap file. But if I do that, then I *don't* need to run it again for `$(NPM_OUT)`. The reason it's in `$(NPM_OUT)` is because I need to run it every time `npm-shrinkwrap.json` changes.

I thought maybe I could create a 3rd target for `npm install` which the other 2 targets could depend on, but unless I specify a dependency file for that too, then it will always run.

How can I handle this?

Comment: If you need to run `install` as a *prerequisite* to creating both `NPM_OUT` and `npm-shrinkwrap.json` then it should be exactly as you say in your last paragraph, a prerequisite of those targets, not a recipe for both. Surely there's some way of figuring out that `install` has been run?

Comment: @user657267 I don't think that will work actually. If I create a 3rd target and have the other two depend on it, then `npm install` won't run when `npm-shrinkwrap.json` changes because it will already have been fulfilled by the dependency.  I want `npm install` to run every time `npm-shrinkwrap.json` changes but I don't want it to run twice if `npm-shrinkwrap.json` doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Can you explain a little more in detail why `npm install` needs to be run before the other two files are created?

Comment: @user657267 [npm shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) records what was installed. You have to install the dependencies before that file can be created. The 2nd time you run `npm install` it uses `npm-shrinkwrap.json` instead of `package.json`. i.e., it attempts to download the exact dependencies you used last time instead of resolving the version constraints again. However, since the 1st install already resolved the dependencies, we don't need to re-install until the shrinkwrap file changes again.

Comment: It's actually not too big of a deal because `npm-shrinkwrap.json` should always exist (it's checked into version control). This is more of an edge-case for when you go nuclear and delete every compiled file from your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say *the npm install is up-to-date* is the state of affairs you want to
proxy with the `NPM_OUT`.

You want *the npm install is up-to-date* to be dependent on `npm-shrinkwrap.json`,
*if and only if* `npm-shrinkwrap.json` exists.  If you manually edit `npm-shrinkwrap.json`,
for instance, then that means the npm install is no longer up to up-to-date and
must be made so, using `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.

But if `npm-shrinkwrap.json` doesn't exist then in fact the *dependency is the
other way round*, because you need to make the npm install up-to-date in
order to make `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, *ab initio*.

So you have different dependencies depending on whether or not `npm-shrinkwrap.json`
exists:

```
NPM_BIRTH_CERT = node_modules/.npm_installed.timestamp
NPM_BIN = $(shell command -v npm || command -v /usr/bin/npm || echo "npm")
NPM_SHRINKWRAP := $(wildcard npm-shrinkwrap.json)

.PHONY: all clean really-clean

all: npm-shrinkwrap.json $(NPM_BIRTH_CERT)

$(NPM_BIRTH_CERT): $(NPM_SHRINKWRAP)
    $(NPM_BIN) install --loglevel=error
    touch $@

ifndef NPM_SHRINKWRAP
npm-shrinkwrap.json: $(NPM_BIRTH_CERT)
    $(NPM_BIN) prune
    $(NPM_BIN) dedupe
    $(NPM_BIN) shrinkwrap --dev
    touch $<
endif

clean:
    rm -fr node_modules

really-clean: clean
    rm -f npm-shrinkwrap.json
```

Here the rule:

```
$(NPM_BIRTH_CERT): $(NPM_SHRINKWRAP)
```

is:

```
$(NPM_BIRTH_CERT): npm-shrinkwrap.json
```

if `npm-shrinkwrap.json` exists and otherwise just:

```
$(NPM_BIRTH_CERT):
```

And whenever `npm-shrinkwrap.json` exists it's not a target at all.

I don't see the need make `$(NPM_BIRTH_CERT)` resolve to an MD5
hash of the `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, rather than just a file that
bears the timestamp of `npm install`s last completion or
`npm-shrinkwrap.json`s last generation from an `npm install`, whichever is latest.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation but I think something is missing here. If `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is missing, then `make node_modules/.npm_installed.timestamp` will not create it. My `build` rule depends on `$(NPM_BIRTH_CERT)` which I was expecting to create `npm-shrinkwrap.json` if it doesn't exist. I guess this isn't *really* a problem though; I can add `$(NPM_SHRINKWRAP)` to the dependencies of `build`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ideas from [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36318212/65387), I think I can get this to behave the way I want:

```
NPM_SHRINKWRAP := $(wildcard npm-shrinkwrap.json)

ifdef NPM_SHRINKWRAP
$(NPM_OUT): npm-shrinkwrap.json
    $(NPM_BIN) install --loglevel=error
    touch $(NPM_OUT)
else
$(NPM_OUT): npm-shrinkwrap.json
endif

npm-shrinkwrap.json: package.json
    $(NPM_BIN) install --loglevel=error --no-shrinkwrap
    $(NPM_BIN) prune
    $(NPM_BIN) dedupe
    $(NPM_BIN) shrinkwrap --dev
    touch $(NPM_OUT)
```

Basically, if the shrinkwrap file exists, then `make $(NPM_OUT)` will run `npm install` iff the shrinkwrap file has been updated.

If the shrinkwrap file doesn't exist, and since `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is still a dependency, the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` target will do the installation instead.

However, I introduced a new problem here: if `npm-shrinkwrap.json` *does* exist *and* package.json (wasn't in original question) has been updated, then the double-install will happen again. I don't know if that can be fixed, or if it's even worth fixing.